# Updating Awesomium version and session changing preferences

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, awesomium

I had some application working in Awesomium 1.6.6 but then I upgraded to 1.7 because I needed to add a new functionality to old application which in old Awesomium version wasn't supported.

But now I run in deeper problems, all the API of Awesomium is different. I have changed much things and now my application works but here are the problems i experience.

I have a problem by changing headers: http://pastebin.com/HrgmAJZS in Awesomium 1.7
**How i accomplish this in new version?**

And I need to change **JavaScript on off by clicking the button on a form**. I have tried this http://pastebin.com/yU3StmWG but it doesn't seems to work.

Here is my full conversation on Awesomium discussion board: http://bit.ly/Zw3Ldi

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The javascript turn off on i have solved by creating an webcontroll dynamically, applying new session to it and adding all handlers to it, also disposing old one. That way it works. Only problem i experience here is that when javascript is disabled none of the website loads not even sites that do not use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug, that crashes a `WebView` or `WebControl`, when `WebPreferences.Javascript` has been set to `false` on the view's `WebSession`. This will be fixed in the final release of version **1.7**.